# How to create a Box-plot of nested/grouped categories in rbokeh?

Tags: r, rbokeh

I need to create a nested category box-plot where the x-axis is a combination of 2 factor(category) groups.
In `ly_boxplot()`, the `x` argument can either be a *numeric vector* or a *factor*. Is there a way that it will accept a combined factor, say, of 2 or more factors?

The picture below is taken from [this link](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/BoxWhisker.html).

How can I create such a plot using `rbokeh` library in R?

[image: Box-plot with a grouped category on the x-axis nested category box-plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `interaction` function.

```
library(rbokeh)
figure(ylab = "Length (mm?)", xlab="Dose (mg/day) : Supplement") %>%
  ly_boxplot(len, interaction(dose,supp), data = ToothGrowth)
```

[image]

Comment: One step forward. Thanks for pointing me to the ```interaction()``` function. However I need to know how can I format the x-axis to have labels appear as the layout posted in my original question. 
As for functionality. your answer did the job!